# Reading TDMS file from LabVIEW on python is so slow?

Tags: python, labview

My TDMS file measured by LabVIEW is just around 170 MB.

When I try to open it:

```
tdms_file = TdmsFile("path_to_file.tdms")
```

The data can be read, but it takes ~1min to run the single line above.
Does that make sense? I thought binary file should be read efficiently.

Comment: Are you using [npTDMS](https://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reading.html)?

Comment: Yes~ Do you have any idea?

Comment: Not really as I don't use TDMS files, but I thought this was an important detail missing from your post. It's not really clear what kind of answers you are looking for though - is the use and format of the TDMS file fixed, or are you open to using a different method of transferring the data? What have you tried? Can you give any more detail on the type and structure of the data in the TDMS file? [This](https://github.com/adamreeve/npTDMS/issues/29) suggests 1 minute for a 170 MB file is not typical, but nobody knows for sure unless you provide more detail.

Comment: Is your TDMS file optimized? If it is heavily interlaced (1 sample multiple channels as a time) when it was created, it will take a long time. Have you tried to defragment the TDMS file (I don't think nptdms has that function)? There's a few pointers in this [blog post](https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/205/labview-data-storage-tdms-performance-tweaking).

Comment: How much time does it take to read the file from Labview?